# How to securely implement biometry with fallback application password to authenticate signing within Secure Enclave?

Tags: ios, swift, cryptography

I am looking to implement a local authentication flow similar to many banking apps in an iOS (Swift) app for using a key in the Secure Enclave:

1. By default you set up an app-specific pin code
2. The user is then able to turn on biometry (Face ID or Touch ID) for quick authentication
3. The user can then sign a message using their private key stored in the Secure Enclave by either using biometrics or the user can fall back to their app-specific pin (either by choice, or if they cancel or can't be recognized for example).

#### What I've tried so far

The [`.applicationPassword`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secaccesscontrolcreateflags/1617930-applicationpassword) flag for [`SecAccessControlCreateFlags`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secaccesscontrolcreateflags) seemed like a reasonable option to allow an application-defined password to be used. Furthermore, the set of possible flags also contain constraints such as such as `devicePasscode` and `biometryCurrentSet` to set access constraints that can even be combined by using [conjunctions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secaccesscontrolcreateflags/1618071-or). It should be noted that `applicationPassword` is not a constraint but an 'option' according to the docs. It's also not very well-documented what this flag actually does. Still, I tried the following:

```
let flags1: SecAccessControlCreateFlags = [.privateKeyUsage,
                                           .biometryCurrentSet, .or, .applicationPassword]
let flags2: SecAccessControlCreateFlags = [.privateKeyUsage,
                                           .biometryCurrentSet, .applicationPassword]

let access1 = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                              kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
                                              flags1,
                                              &error)
let access2 = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                              kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
                                              flags2,
                                              &error)
```

Both of these options seem to work essentially the same, where first the phone prompts for biometric verification and then shows a prompt where you can enter the application password.
I tried programmatically supplying the application password using `LAContext.setCredential`, and this works fine as the application password prompt will no longer be shown, but iOS will still always prompt for biometrics as well (even when using the `.or` flag). Thus, it seems that the `.or` flag is not working as I had hoped together with `.applicationPassword`. However, these access control policies do seem to enforce that both biometrics and application password should pass, which is a nice possibility but not exactly what I was looking for.
I have also tried preventing the respective prompts such as the Face ID prompt from being shown with `LAContext.interactionNotAllowed` but this also does not work because of the access control flags.

#### Basic setup

For testing this, I have a simple iOS app set up with the following functions derived from the [Secure Enclave documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/protecting_keys_with_the_secure_enclave):

```
func getAccessControl() -> SecAccessControl {
    var access: SecAccessControl?
    
    access = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                             kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
                                             [.privateKeyUsage,
                                              .biometryCurrentSet,
                                              .or,
                                              .applicationPassword],
                                             nil)!
    return access
}

func generatePrivateKey() throws -> SecKey {
    let context = LAContext()
    context.setCredential("pwd123".data(using: .utf8), type: .applicationPassword)
    
    let attributes: NSDictionary = [
        kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 256,
        kSecAttrTokenID: kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave,
        kSecUseAuthenticationContext as String: context,
        kSecAttrLabel: "label-for-reference",
        kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
        kSecPrivateKeyAttrs: [
            kSecAttrIsPermanent: true,
            kSecAttrApplicationTag: "tag-for-reference",
            kSecAttrAccessControl: getAccessControl(),
        ]
    ]
    
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    guard let privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes, &error) else {
        throw error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
    }
    
    return privateKey
}

func retrieveKey(context: LAContext? = nil) -> SecKey? {
    var attributes: [String: Any] = [
        kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
        kSecAttrLabel as String: "label-for-reference",
        kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne,
        kSecReturnRef as String: true,
    ]
    if let context = context {
        attributes[kSecUseAuthenticationContext as String] = context
    }
    
    var item: CFTypeRef?
    let res = SecItemCopyMatching(attributes as CFDictionary, &item)
    
    if (res == errSecSuccess) {
        return (item as! SecKey)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func sign(data: String, key: SecKey) throws -> Data? {
    if (SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported(key, .sign, .ecdsaSignatureMessageX962SHA256)) {
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        guard let signature = SecKeyCreateSignature(key,
                                                    .ecdsaSignatureMessageX962SHA256,
                                                    data.data(using: .utf8)! as CFData,
                                                    &error) as Data? else {
            throw error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
        }
        return signature
    }
    return nil
}
```

I can then generate a signature by doing something like this (leaving out some details):

```
let privateKey = generatePrivateKey()

let context = LAContext()
context.setCredential("pwd123".data(using: .utf8), type: .applicationPassword)
let retrievedKey = retrieveKey(context)

var signedMessage: Data?
try signedMessage = sign(data: "abc", key: retrievedKey!))
```

#### What I'd like to learn

I'd like to learn if I'm missing something in this documentation (specifically on the access control of [secure enclave] keychain items), or alternatively, if there is a particular workaround to make this work. For example, I've also thought about chaining the access options, e.g. `Face ID --unlocks--> Application passcode --unlocks--> Private key` so that the application passcode can either be provided by using Face ID first or directly by the user. However, this would load the application passcode in memory (which may not be an issue when the user already enters their pin code in a custom user interface anyway). How do apps with similar functionality generally solve this?